Generate a diagram representing a complex neural network with neurons and connections in Keras?
I'm starting my studies in Neural Networks and I learn better by visualizing things.
I've created a simple neural sequential model using keras Sequential function:
model = Sequential([
    Dense(units = 16, input_shape = (1,), activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')
])

Now I want to visualize it, as in a similar shape as this neural network diagram:

I've tried chatGPT and gemini to generate diagrams in a similar shape but no success. How can I do so?
I tried using this line
plot_model(model, to_file='model_diagram.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)

